# operator[] returns reference or copy depending on variable type

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference

Referencing [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/), if I have a `std::map<double, Object> my_map`, are the following equivalent?

```
Object& obj = my_map[1];
Object obj = my_map[1];
```

I know `operator[]` returns by reference, so is the first way, the correct way to do it and not create a copy, or are they the same. If they are the same, I am not sure as to why they would be.

Similarly, if I also have...

```
std::map<double, Object>::iterator it;
```

Are the following similar as well?

```
Object& obj = it->second;
Object obj = it->second;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Object& obj = my_map[1];
Object obj = my_map[1];
```

These are not equivalent ( if nothing else, there's a whole ampersand of difference :) ). The first one creates a reference to the object that's existing inside the map, the second one creates a copy of it (and it requires an accesible copy constructor of `Object`).

The iterator-style lines achieve the same thing as the first two that call `operator[]`.

Comment: Maybe mention copy construction?

Comment: @Paranaix Fair enough, did that.

Comment: @jrok thanks for the answer, quick followup, if I try to use a variable in the Object by using it->second.somevariable, it is accessed by reference and it->second doesn't create a copy?

Comment: @Joshua Yes, `it->second` gives you the object itself, an lvalue. No copy is being made.